ros-noetic-ros-base - Unmet dependencies in ubuntu 20.04
I have Ubuntu 20.04 distro and cmake 3.25 installed which is the version required for my project, but when I try to install ros-noetic-ros-base I am getting unmet dependencies issue, it is expecting cmake 3.29.6-0kitware1ubuntu22.04, How do i install it with current installed version.
Investigating (0) ros-noetic-catkin:amd64 < none -> 0.8.10-1focal.20210423.221558 @un uN Ib >
Broken ros-noetic-catkin:amd64 Depends on cmake:amd64 < none | 3.29.6-0kitware1ubuntu22.04.1 @un uH >
Considering cmake:amd64 1 as a solution to ros-noetic-catkin:amd64 33
Holding Back ros-noetic-catkin:amd64 rather than change cmake:amd64
Investigating (0) ros-noetic-roslib:amd64 < none -> 1.15.8-1focal.20210727.060939 @un uN Ib >
I tried using
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable lsb_release -cs main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
then used aptitude for installing but still gives same error. Request help on installing it in the required environment I have
